# Different product images on Thumbnail, Featured Product image on both desktop and mobile on Woocommerce

Tags: image, woocommerce, e-commerce, product

Is there a way, a plugin maybe, where I can upload a different image for the thumbnail in the shop, featured product image for desktop, and the featured product for mobile devices for Woocommerce.

Example, I upload image A for the thumbnail, image B for the featured product in desktop, and switches to image C as soon as it is on mobile.

I thought of using CSS for this, but I think it is too tedious to make for all of the products. I want the user to do this while on the Edit Product page on Woocommerce.

Also, I don't have adequate knowledge in making a plugin.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know of any plugins to do this but it's certainly possible to write your own code to achieve this.  Might be time to hire a developer ;)

Comment: Thanks. In your opinion, what technologies should I use to achieve this? PHP, CSS, and JS?

Comment: It's just going to be PHP mainly to write a plugin.